# Using DAX in PowerPivot to find out value of a column based on MAX / IF another

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I'm trying to write a DAX formula that finds the maximum YearMonth and returns the liability IF the points earned are >0.  So in the example below the returning value would be 190.

I've spent ages trying to get this to work without any luck, so if anyone can help I'd be really grateful

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| YearMonth | Points Earned | Liability |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
|    200506 |            86 |       170 |
|    200507 |            22 |       150 |
|    200508 |            45 |       190 |
|    200509 |             0 |       190 |
|    200510 |             0 |       190 |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

*Apologies about the formatting of the table, I couldn't work out how to insert it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two measures `MaxYearMonth` and `LastLiability`.

```
MaxYearMonth :=
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( [YearMonth] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Table ), [Points Earned] > 0 )
)
```

```
LastLiability :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table[Liability] ),
    FILTER ( Table, Table[YearMonth] = [MaxYearMonth] )
)
```

The `LastLiability` measure calculates the `Liability` by using the `MaxYearMonth` measure. `MaxYearMonth` measure calculates the last YearMonth which Points Earned value is greater than 0.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Alejandro, you've made my day - this does the trick exactly as I wanted.  Thanks so much!!